# In PHP, how do I create a multi-line variable without escaping quotes?

Tags: php, coldfusion

In CFML there is the construct:

```
<cfsavecontent name="HTML_content">
    <div class="test_div" style="color:#FFF;">Test</div>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Within PHP there seems to be no way of doing this without some really hacky function or escaping double quotes. I'm trying to create emails (large html documents) within the same page by saving the email content and simply mailing it but it seems like there's no way of doing this within PHP without using `$var = "\"bad code\""`;

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

---

I'v tried the [answer by deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540564/9360) below

```
$var = <<<HTML
    <div class="test_div" style="color:#FFF;">Test</div>
HTML;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_END_HEREDOC or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in C:\vhosts\jpl\pages\about\testimonials.php on line 29
```

---

For anyone else that is stuck on this,
The HTML; part at the end of the HEREDOCS example needs to be right at the beginning (no tabs, spaces or anything) of the end.

So <kbd>newline</kbd> <kbd>HTML;</kbd> not <kbd>newline</kbd> <kbd>[tab or space]</kbd> <kbd>HTML;</kbd>

Comment: It'd be nice if you could leave out the thinly disguised rant. It appears you like ColdFusion a lot, but that's no reason to call everything else "crap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = '<div class="test_div" style="color:#FFF;">Test</div>';

$var = <<<HTML
    <div class="test_div" style="color:#FFF;">Test</div>
HTML;
```

So many ways to quote a string... http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Also consider putting the email contents into a separate file and `include`ing it where needed.

Comment: You see I do the code you've mentioned above and it breaks with the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_END_HEREDOC or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in C:\vhosts\jpl\pages\about\testimonials.php on line 29

Comment: Then you did not do Heredocs correctly. Please read the beforelinked manual entry and pay close attention to what it says.

Comment: Be sure that `HTML;` starts at the very beginning of the line. No spacese before it.

Comment: Thanks got it working, you can't have a leading space after the end of the document, ie. HTML; needs to be right after the declaration.