# php equivalent for coldfusion cfsavecontent

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am attempting to convert a coldfusion base site template that I use everyday in coldfusion to php.

In coldfusion I have a cfsavecontent that holds a block of data that I display.

here is an example:

```
       <cfoutput>
    <cfsavecontent variable="content">
        <div class="container-fluid content">
            <h3>Hello World</h3>

        </div>
        <cfinclude template="modal/modal.cfm">
    </cfsavecontent>
</cfoutput>

<cfinclude template="includes/template.cfm">
```

What would be the php version of cfsavecontent.  Or is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do I create a multi-line variable without escaping quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540533/in-php-how-do-i-create-a-multi-line-variable-without-escaping-quotes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given this CFML:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="content">
    Some text<br>
    <cfif randRange(0,1)>
        <cfset result = "value if true">
    <cfelse>
        <cfset result = "and if it's false">
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput>#result#</cfoutput><br>
    Message from include is:
    <cfinclude template="./inc.cfm">
</cfsavecontent>

<cfoutput>#content#</cfoutput>
```

And the include:

```
<cfset greeting = "G'day">
<cfoutput>#greeting#</cfoutput><br>
```

A PHP analogue would be:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Some text" . PHP_EOL;
if (rand(0,1)){
    $result = "value if true";
}else{
    $result = "and if it's false";
}
echo $result . PHP_EOL;
echo "Message from include is: ";
include __DIR__ . "\inc.php";

echo ob_get_clean();
```

inc.php:

```
<?php
$greeting = "G'day";
echo $greeting . PHP_EOL;
```

So you want to look at "[Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)" in the docs.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  That is exactly what I was looking for but could not find.  Thanks also for linking to the docs for further reading.